# Updated AutoMapper from 3 to 4 broke inheritance mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I updated AutoMapper from 3.3.1 to 4.0.4 which broke the following mapping with this message

> Unable to cast object of type 'Foo' to type 'BarDTO'

**Classes**

```
public class FooDTO
{
    // omitted
}

// derived DTO
public class BarDTO : FooDTO
{
    public string Extra { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping config**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDTO>().ReverseMap();
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, BarDTO>();
```

**Mapping**

```
Map<Foo, BarDTO>(foo); // throws cast exception
```

I also tried using the `.Include()` method, but didn't make a difference.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDTO>()
      .Include<Foo, BarDTO>()
      .ReverseMap();
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, BarDTO>();
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known change happened from 3.x.x to 4. Configuring the mapping inside Mapper.Initialize would solve the problem.

e.g.
In 3.x.x mapping is done like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
            .Include<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>()
            .Include<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
```

Now, In 4.x.x mapping should be done in Initialize method using delegate.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
                .Include<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>()
                .Include<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
            cfg.CreateMap<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>();
            cfg.CreateMap<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
        });
```

Here's the discussion related to the [issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/819) .

> Update ver: bug fixed for 4.1.0 milestone

Alternatively, you can do is seal the mappings.

```
Mapper.Configuration.Seal();
```

Comment: The issue was added to milestone 4.1.0 so it appears to be a bug :)

Comment: I don't know who -1ed this post. Updated the post to add the recent fix done. Now the `Mapper.Configuration.Seal()` method can be used instead to have the Automapper figure out the Mapper strategy.