# Automapper inheritance mapping not working after upgrade. V3.3.1.0 -> V4.0.4.0

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map multiple domain objects to their responding DTO's

**Domain**

```
public abstract class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class OnlineOrder : Order
{
    public string Referrer { get; set; }
}
public class MailOrder : Order
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**DTO**

```
public abstract class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class OnlineOrderDto : OrderDto
{
    public string Referrer { get; set; }
}
public class MailOrderDto : OrderDto
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Map Definition**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .Include<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>()
    .Include<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<OnlineOrder, OrderDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<MailOrder, OrderDto>();
```

**Object Mapping**

```
var orders = new List<Order>()
    {
        new OnlineOrder { Referrer = "Google", Id = 123 }, 
        new MailOrder() { Address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway", Id = 124}
    };
var mapped = Mapper.Map<List<OrderDto>>(orders);
```

I would expect Automapper to be able to discern the type passed in and using the definition specified to choose the appropriate source and destination. i.e. an *OnlineOrder* would be mapped to an *OnlineOrderDto* and a *MailOrder* I would be mapped to a *MailOrderDto*. This is not the case as I get an "Instances of abstract classes cannot be created" error. I'm almost certain I have used a similar pattern before but I've hit a wall and any help would be appreciated.

**Update: It would seem that this is only a problem after upgrading to the latest version of Automapper V4.0.4.0.**

Comment: similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141447/updated-automapper-from-3-to-4-broke-inheritance-mapping/32142076).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is a known [issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/819) and would require a code change. Change your initialization to -

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg .CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
              .Include<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>()
              .Include<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
              cfg.CreateMap<OnlineOrder, OrderDto>();
              cfg.CreateMap<MailOrder, OrderDto>();
        });
```

> Update ver: bug fixed for 4.1.0 milestone

Alternatively, you can do is seal the mappings.

```
Mapper.Configuration.Seal();
```

Comment: Although I didn't use this exact solution it pointed out the issue that my Google-Fu could not. I already have my Automapper configuration startup managed by Autofac so instead of changing the way that worked I simply called Mapper.Configuration.Seal() after registering my Autofac IStartable configuration. Thanks vendettamit.

Comment: This is new since I last used it. Thanks for sharing I didn't know abt the seal method.

Comment: Updated the answer with recent bug fix.